# Pandas compiled from source: default pickle behavior changed

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I've just compiled and installed pandas from source (cloned github repo, `>>> setup.py install`).

It happened that the default behavior of module `pickle` for object serialization/deserialization changed being likely partially overridden by pandas internal modules.

I have quite some data classes serialized via "standard" `pickle` which apparently I cannot deserialize anymore; in particular, when I try to deserialize a class file (surely working), I get this error

```
In [1]: import pickle

In [2]: pickle.load(open('pickle_L1cor_s1.pic','rb'))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-88719f8f9506> in <module>()
----> 1 pickle.load(open('pickle_L1cor_s1.pic','rb'))

/home/acorbe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load(file)
   1376
   1377 def load(file):
-> 1378     return Unpickler(file).load()
   1379
   1380 def loads(str):

/home/acorbe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load(self)
    856             while 1:
    857                 key = read(1)
--> 858                 dispatch[key](self)
    859         except _Stop, stopinst:
    860             return stopinst.value

/home/acorbe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0_1090_g46008ec-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/compat/pickle_compat.pyc in load_reduce(self)
     28
     29         # try to reencode the arguments
---> 30         if self.encoding is not None:
     31             args = tuple([ arg.encode(self.encoding) if isinstance(arg, string_types)     else arg for arg in args ])
     32             try:

AttributeError: Unpickler instance has no attribute 'encoding'
```

I have quite a large code relying on this which broke down. Is there any quick workaround? How can I obtain again default pickle behavior?

any help appreciated

---

**EDIT:**

I realized that what I am willing to unpickle is a list of dicts which include a couple of `DataFrames` each. That's where pandas comes into play.

I applied the patch by @Jeff github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5661.
Another error (maybe related to [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4744)) shows up.

```
In [4]: pickle.load(open('pickle_L1cor_s1.pic','rb'))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-88719f8f9506> in <module>()
----> 1 pickle.load(open('pickle_L1cor_s1.pic','rb'))

/home/acorbe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load(file)
   1376
   1377 def load(file):
-> 1378     return Unpickler(file).load()
   1379
   1380 def loads(str):

/home/acorbe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load(self)
    856             while 1:
    857                 key = read(1)
--> 858                 dispatch[key](self)
    859         except _Stop, stopinst:
    860             return stopinst.value

/home/acorbe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in             load_reduce(self)
   1131         args = stack.pop()
   1132         func = stack[-1]
-> 1133         value = func(*args)
   1134         stack[-1] = value
   1135     dispatch[REDUCE] = load_reduce

TypeError: _reconstruct: First argument must be a sub-type of ndarray
```

Pandas version of encoded data is (from Canopy package manager)

```
Size: 7.32 MB
Version: 0.12.0
Build: 2
Dependencies:
 numpy 1.7.1
 python_dateutil
 pytz 2011n

  md5: 7dd4385bed058e6ac15b0841b312ae35
```

I am not sure I can provide minimal example of the files I am trying to unpickle. 
They are quite large (O(100MB)) and they have some non trivial dependencies.

Comment: can u show the exact code u r doing as well as the pickle file (a link from Dropbox if u can)

Comment: you can always unpickle before u load in pandas (as a work around)

Comment: @Jeff,the one I posted is exactly the code I use. No pandas involved explicitly. After I did the pandas installation, the unpickle calls (even unrelated to pandas) to load the files I am working with broke down. Files are larger than 100mb

Comment: I need something to reproduce. You have to have loaded pandas before this, otherwise the code won't exist. Can you post a link to the file?

Comment: give this branch a try (or you can just temporarily edit the code, only a couple of lines), lmk: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5661

Comment: Acorbe, you may be importing pandas from your IPython startup profile.

Comment: if u can post in Dropbox would be gr8. 100mb is not very big. did you pickle this is 0.12? can u provide an example of what u pickled?

Comment: @Jeff, I replied on github with the file. Meet you there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Master has just been updated by this [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5661).

This file be read simply by:

```
 result = pd.read_pickle('pickle_L1cor_s1.pic')
```

The objects that are pickled are pandas <= 0.12 versioned. This need a custom unpickler, which
the 0.13/master (releasing shortly) handles. 0.13 saw a refactor of the Series inheritance hierarchy where Series is no longer a sub-class of `ndarray`, but now of `NDFrame`, the same base class of `DataFrame` and `Panel`. This was done for a great many reasons, mainly to promote code consistency. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0130-refactoring) for a more complete description.

The error message you are seeing `` `TypeError: _reconstruct: First argument must be a sub-type of ndarray `` is that the python default unpickler makes sure that the class hierarchy that was pickled is exactly the same what it is recreating. Since Series has changed between versions this is no longer possible with the default unpickler, (this IMHO is a bug in the way pickle works). In any event, pandas will unpickle pre-0.13 pickles that have Series objects.

Comment: So does that mean if I have a `numpy` function which returns a series or dataframe when called on one, that's an issue to be addressed?

Comment: I don't think so; only a saved series/frame in 0.12 or prior when attempting to unpickle in 0.13. a function def is ok

Comment: Ah, sorry, I may have worded that badly.  There are lots of numpy functions which still return Series when passed Series.  I thought that was a feature, and I may have relied on it a few times, but the what's-new you linked to says maybe I was mistaken?

Comment: numpy functions uses __array__ (which is almost all of them, except np.where) to return a series if passed a series. this is a run-time feature and will not have an impact with pickles.

Comment: Yeah, it was the live stuff which was puzzling me.  I misread the refactoring section to mean that we should only expect to get ndarrays back now if we applied a numpy function on a Series or DataFrame.  All is good. :^)

Comment: @Jeff, YES!! It works great!! Thanks.. I've switched back to version v0.12, now I will use updated code. I have to change all my unpickle calls, no way out, right?

Comment: @Acorbe gr8. pd.read_pickle just calls I pickle under the hood. (well it opens and closes the file too). more importantly it handles the compat issues. so if u r expecting to use lots of back and forth between 0.12/0.13 then I would change the calls. FYI you can use pd.to_pickle for arbitrary objects as well