# Is pandas.read_pickle() performance crippled in version 0.13?

Tags: python, pandas

After upgrading to pandas 0.13 from 0.12, I noticed that large pickle files were taking 
much longer to load with `pandas.read_pickle()`.  It seems like 0.13 no longer uses cPickle for reading - is that intentional??

My test dataset has pickled file size 1.6Gb, and contains about 13 million records.

With 0.12 the file takes 146s to load; with 0.13 is takes 982s (about 6.7x longer).

I first thought it was because I wrote the pickle file with 0.12 and read with 0.13, and it was forced to use compatibility mode (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444593/pandas-compiled-from-source-default-pickle-behavior-changed)).  But even if I save the file again from 0.13, it still uses native python pickle instead of cPickle to read it.  I watched with cProfile to verify. Looking at the source [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/pickle.py) and [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/compat/pickle_compat.py) it does seems clear that it will use cPickle to write, but will always use native python pickle to load.

If I use `cPickle.load(open('foo.pickle'))` instead of `pandas.read_pickle('foo.pickle')` (which I guess is only safe if you know the pickle version is the same?) then I get my factor of six back.

Is `to_pickle/read_pickle` no longer the recommended approach, or is this a bug??

Comment: This looks like a bug! (that's a pretty bad perf hit, from using pandas.compat's version of pkl.) :s

Comment: prob could use cpickle if not in compat mode (which had to use reg pickle); maybe file a bug report

Comment: And I got bit by this the same day! Definitely a bug...

Comment: Thanks, filed https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6899  The workaround of using cPickle.load() directly is easy enough for now.

Comment: A fix was just committed for this.  It was also suggested that I should be using df.to_hdf('out.h5') and pandas.read_hdf('out.h5') since they perform better than pickles anyway - good to know!