# Trouble opening old pickle file

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I am trying to load an old pickle file containing the airline dataset ( https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06740 ) . The pickle is very old and I have problems accessing it. If I try:

```
objects = []
with (open("airline.pickle", "rb")) as openfile:
    while True:
        try:
            objects.append(pickle.load(openfile))
        except EOFError:
            break
```

I get the following warning and error:

```
FutureWarning: pandas.core.index is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  The public classes are available in the top-level namespace.
  objects.append(pickle.load(openfile))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\LocalAdmin\surfdrive\Code\Python\Airline\pickleToCSV.py", line 9, in <module>
    objects.append(pickle.load(openfile))
TypeError: _reconstruct: First argument must be a sub-type of ndarray
```

Trying with pandas does not work:

```
  File "C:\Users\LocalAdmin\surfdrive\Code\Python\Airline\Airline\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 203, in read_pickle
    return pickle.load(handles.handle)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
TypeError: _reconstruct: First argument must be a sub-type of ndarray

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\LocalAdmin\surfdrive\Code\Python\Airline\pickleToCSV.py", line 7, in <module>
    df = pd.read_pickle('airline.pickle')
  File "C:\Users\LocalAdmin\surfdrive\Code\Python\Airline\Airline\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 208, in read_pickle
    return pc.load(handles.handle, encoding=None)
  File "C:\Users\LocalAdmin\surfdrive\Code\Python\Airline\Airline\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py", 
line 249, in load
    return up.load()
  File "C:\Users\LocalAdmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pickle.py", line 1212, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "C:\Users\LocalAdmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pickle.py", line 1725, in load_build
    for k, v in state.items():
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How can I access the file and save it to csv? I need the data that is contained there. I am using pandas 1.2.4 and python 3.6.

Comment: First, it seems like you are using Python 3.9 and not 3.6 (`...Python39\lib\pickle.py`). Second, try using the same Python version as the one used to pickle the file, maybe the pickling format changed in the later versions of the library.

Comment: "The pickle is very old" How much do you know about the exact conditions under which it was pickled?

Comment: The paper is from 2017, but the data is probably older (range from 2013-2016)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27956545/4080973), the error `TypeError: _reconstruct: First argument must be a sub-type of ndarray` is due to a change from pandas version 0.14 to 0.15 [(Source)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.15.0.html#whatsnew-0150-refactoring). The documentation said that `pd.read_pickle` would be able to load such old pickle files, but this is not working on recent versions. If you install an older version, I tested 0.17.1 which can be obtained in pypi or conda-forge, it can load that pickle file successfully.

If you are using conda, the following should work:

```bash
conda create -n old_pandas -c conda-forge pandas=0.17.* python=3.*
conda activate old_pandas
```

And then, in a Python prompt,

```py
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_pickle("airline.pickle")
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax should be simpler than in your example

```
with open("airline.pickle", "rb") as f:
    objects = pickle.load(f)
```

If this fails, then I would look at the [pickle  documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler) which covers some of the optional parameters that are useful for decoding pickle files created by python2.

Comment: It raises a new error: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'new_block' on <module 'pandas.core.internals.blocks' from 'D:\\anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\internals\\blocks.py'>`

Comment: got same error in similar situation